Converting 2-column text file to key/value pairs
I am currently learning Node.js and Express. I'm trying to convert a text file into key-value pairs.
My staircase program works like this:

The provided text file looks like this (with 300 lines):
I want a conversion that creates an array that looks, more or less, like this:
{283: 'land'}
{45: 'sun'}
{149: 'too'}
{258: 'huge'}
{161: 'dont'}`

The first column items become the keys and the second column items become the values. This result will become a constant where I can call on the number (key) and get the word (value).
I've succeeded at converting to JSON with headers at the top of the columns, then removing all of the unwanted info to result in just the number and the word.
I had to edit the text file to make perfectly spaced columns and add the headers:
json_num        json_word
283             land
45              sun
149             too
258             huge
161             dont...

The code I'm using:
const express = require("express");
const dataToJson = require("data-to-json");

const app = express();
const port = "3000";

const dataInJSON = dataToJson.txt({ filePath: "./coding_qual_input.txt" }).toJson();

console.log(dataInJSON)
const dataLength = dataInJSON.length;
        
function create_staircase(nums) {
    var subsets = [];
    var step = 1;
    while (nums.length !== 0) {  
      if (step === subsets.length+1) {
        subsets = nums.slice(0, step);
        const value = (dataInJSON.find((dataInJSON) => dataInJSON.json_num == (subsets[step-1])));
        console.log(value.json_num, value.json_word);
        nums.splice(0, step);
        step++;
    } else {
        subsets = nums.splice(0, subsets.length+1);
        nums.splice(0, step);
        step++;
      }
      }  
    } 

    const arrayRange = (start, stop, step) =>
    Array.from(
    { length: (stop - start) / step + 1 },
    (value, index) => start + index * step
    );
  create_staircase(arrayRange(1, dataLength, 1));
  
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Battleship ${port} Cats listening, over!`);
});

And the result is roughly this:
1 design
3 all
6 skill
10 whole
15 check
21 deal
28 wish
36 visit...

Is there a more elegant way to convert the provided text data to key/value pairs?
Please excuse my fledgling use of terminology and do ask for more info if I left out something critical.

The dataToJson library is not needed, and your create_staircase function's logic is somewhat unclear:

You are incrementing step and slicing from nums based on step, but the logic inside the if-else blocks seems to be overly complicated.
You seem to use splice() to remove elements from the array at a growing rate, but the condition contains logic that modifies nums and subsets in a non-typical way.

Are you trying to display or process data in batches that increase in size?
Don't use find here, it's not efficient if dataInJSON is large because it performs a linear search.
Tips:

Directly parse the file using fs and split by whitespace.
Simplify the staircase logic to incrementally display more data.
Remove repeated searches by working with sorted keys.

More efficient/improved code:
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

function convertFileToJSON(filePath) {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
    const lines = fileContent.split('\n');
    const result = {};
    lines.forEach(line => {
        // remove leading/trailing whitespace, split string into an array of substrings (one of more spaces)
        const parts = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
        if (parts.length === 2) {
            result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
        }
    });
    return result;
}

const dataInJSON = convertFileToJSON('./coding_qual_input.txt');
const keys = Object.keys(dataInJSON).map(Number).sort((a, b) => a - b);

function createStaircase(keys) {
    let step = 1;
    let index = 0;
    while (index < keys.length) {
        const subset = keys.slice(index, index + step);
        subset.forEach(key => {
            console.log(`${key}: ${dataInJSON[key]}`);
        });
        index += step;
        step++;
    }
}

createStaircase(keys);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Battleship ${port} Cats listening, over!`);
});


Thank you so much, @christian! I knew there was a better way. I'll check this out tomorrow and I may or may not come back with more questions.

This code is much cleaner, but the result is kind of randomizing rather than creating a proper staircase. However, I think I have enough to work with to figure it out. Thanks again!

Oh, I missed this and now adjusted my code to consider the index.
